# MySQL replication Master-Slave

Tags: mysql, database, replication, database-replication, master-slave

I am about to do a MySQL replication for my typo3 Database. There are two servers. You guessed it one is the Master and one is the Slave.

Master my.cnf:

`[mysql]

server-id = 1

log-bin

expire_logs_days = 21

max_binlog_size = 500M

binlog-ignore-db=mysql`

Slave my.cnf:

`[mysql]

server-id = 2

binlog-ignore-db = mysql

replicate-ignore-db = mysql

auto-increment-offset = 1

expire_logs_days = 21

max_binlog_size = 500M`

User on Master: `repl@slaveip   REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT`
User on Slave: `repl@masterip   REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT`

So far everything works, even if I change something on Master but if I delete the same thing on Master, Slave stops with this error message:

`Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry '65021' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'typo3'. Query: 'INSERT INTO sys_log (userid,type,action,error,details_nr,details,IP,tstamp,workspace) VALUES ('0','5','0','2','0','Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Reason: Segment &quot;404&quot; was not a keyword for a postVarSet as expected on page with id=0.<br />\n<br />\nAdditionally, http://www.21cdocs.de/404/ was not found while trying to retrieve the error document. | RuntimeException thrown in file /mnt/platte02/www/typo3/typo3_src-4.5.19/typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/class.tslib_fe.php in line 1542','masterip','1351240603','0')'`

This is what `show slave status\G` shows me.

Any solutions how I force the Slave to override *everything* on it with Masters data?

- Timo

Answer (score 0):

With `slave-skip-errors = 1062` it skips the error but this isn't a good solution in my opinion

**Update**: obviously Typo3 is doing some mistakes on the sys_log table.